# Is it possible to save a base64 string as an image in a image file using only PhantomJS?

Tags: phantomjs, base64

I'm trying to capture a particular element on a web page using PhantomJS. Using getBoundingClientRect(), I'm able to clip Off the unnecessary elements(for which the entire page gets rendered and then clipped). Now I'm to trying to focus and capture a particular canvas component and store it in an image file. Once base64 string is obtained, how do I save base64 string as an image in an image file without the aid of any utility like casperjs? The below code doesn't work for me.

```
img = chart1.canvas.toDataURL();
ext = img.split(';')[0].match(/jpeg|png|gif/)[0];
data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
fs.write('myChart.png', data, 'w');
```